# Ember.js How can the URL represent every possible router state?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

On the documentation for routing at emberjs.com, it states

> Is the user currently logged in? Are they an admin user? What post are they looking at? Is the settings screen open? Are they editing the current post?
>   In Ember.js, **each of the possible states** in your application is represented by a URL.

I can't seem to understand: How is it supposed to happen to have every possible of the above states is represented by a URL?

Explanation:

As far as i can see, the Ember Router is a strictly hierarchical tree structure. That makes perfect sense to me for straightforward URLs, e.g.

`user/:user_id/posts/:post_id/comments`

which is the locator for the comments of a single post.

Now, where would the login state of the user go? Wouldn't that create multiple URLS for the same resource, or does that not matter?

If your settings screen is a modal that can be accessed from anywhere on the site, how would that be reflected in the url?

I'm not asking for a workaround solution, but just wanted to get some opinions of how this is actually meant in the guides or what the best practises are.

Answer (score 1):

Great question Conrad.

I'll offer some experience from the multiple projects I've done in Ember.

1. Rarely do I add the user to the route, there's a good chance you aren't going to be sending down anything but the current logged in user (unless of course you're building an admin resource). So defining the user id in the url is probably incorrect, since it doesn't define the current page, it defines the user who was viewing that current page.
2. The login state would be unrelated to the other resource routes.  It would live at the root, and after login you would redirect to an authorized route.  In the event that someone navigates directly to an authorized route, there are some good patterns for pausing that transition, navigating to the login route, then upon a valid login redirecting to the authorized route.
3. Generally you have multiple routes for a single resource.

   ```
   App.Router.map(function() {
      this.resource('login');
      this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
        this.route('edit');
        this.route('someViewWithTheSameResource');
        this.route('someViewWithTheSameResource2');
        this.resource('comments', function() {
           this.route('new');
           this.route('update');
        });
      });
    });
   ```
4. The grand-daddy issue is modals.  Originally that was just a don't handle it in the url, there is no nice way to handle this without having to add a million routes under different settings.  With the upcoming change of query params you can modify settings at a root level without having to muck up the entire resource tree.  This is still in beta, so it may not quite work as expected, but the goal is to be able to handle such a use case.

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/